# Django: Error when creating objects using from

Tags: python, django, web, django-forms, view

I'v been trying to use form to insert comment. When user type comment it gets article number, username, and comment body and redirect to the previous page. However It keeps display error message, and I couldn't find exactly which part I missed.

This is model.py

```
class Comment(models.Model):
article_no = models.IntegerField(default=1)
comment_no = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
comment_writer = models.CharField(max_length=50)
comment_body = models.CharField(max_length=300)
comment_date = models.DateTimeField(editable=False, default=datetime.now())
```

forms.py

```
class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):

class Meta:
    model = Comment
    fields = ['article_no', 'comment_body', 'comment_writer']
```

view.py

```
@login_required
def comment(request, article_no):
user = request.user
request.session['username'] = user.username
if 'username' is None:
    return render(request, 'blog/home.html')
else:

    if request.POST.has_key('comment_body') == False:
        return HttpResponse('comment is none')
    else:
        if len(request.POST['comment_body']) == 0:
            return HttpResponse('comment is none')
        else:
            comment_body = request.POST['comment_body']
            print(comment_body)

    if request.POST.has_key('comment_writer') == False:
        return HttpResponse('writer is none')
    else:
        if len(request.POST['comment_writer']) == 0:
            return HttpResponse('comment is none')
        else:
            comment_writer = request.POST['comment_writer']
            print(comment_writer)

    try:        

            instance = CommentForm(Comment_body=comment_body, Comment_writer=comment_writer, Article_no=article_no)
            instance.save()
            instance.Comment += 1
            instance.save()
            #return HttpResponse('comment added')
            item = get_object_or_404(Article, pk=article_no)

            return render(request, 'blog/detail.html', {'item': item})

    except:
        print("A")
        return HttpResponse('error')
    print("B")
return HttpResponse('error')
```

urls.py

```
url(r'^comment/(?P<article_no>[0-9]+)/$', views.comment, name='comment'),
```

Comment: What error message is it displaying?

Comment: post what your getting?

Comment: @EvansMurithi It says ' __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'comment_body' '. So I thought that this could be caused by putting capital letter on field name so I changed it into lower. However the result is the same.

Comment: It seems like It succeeded to get comment writer, comment body, article number but just failed to create or insert row in database.

Comment: `instance = CommentForm(Comment_body=comment_body, Comment_writer=comment_writer, Article_no=article_no)
            instance.save()` is wrong. You pass a dict (usually `request.POST`) or `initial=dict`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a *lot* of very very odd code in this question. Some pointers:

- There is no point in setting `username` in the session, since the user is already available via the request.
- `if 'username' is None` compares the literal string "username" with None, which is never going to be True.
- You should redirect to the home page if the user is not logged in, not render the home page template.
- Don't use `has_key`; the correct way to determine if a dict has a key is `if key in dict`.
- Don't compare things with `== False`. The result of the expression (`in` or `has_key`) is already a boolean which is true or false.
- You completely ignore the form, since you compare all the values directly with `request.POST`. You should be using the `form.cleaned_data` dict after calling `form.is_valid()`.
- But you don't need to compare those things anyway, since they are precisely the things that are caught by form validation; that's the whole point.
- You can't pass keyword arguments to a form. You pass the data dictionary, ie `request.POST`. Then call `is_valid` and `save`.
- The result of instantiating a form class is, well, a form instance, not a  model instance. The model instance comes from calling `form.save()`.
- `instance.Comment += 1` literally makes no sense at all; neither the form nor the model has a Comment attribute.
- *Never ever ever* do a blank try/except. That just hides the errors. Remove those statements completely.

Comment: Thank you so much, I changed my code  and It become better than before.